# Is Ash's charizard released or is it at Oak's place?

Tags: pokemon

In bulbpedia it says Ash's Charizard *Pokémon* is at Oak's, but in other places I read that he was released to the Charicific Valley.

What really happened, what should I believe? Was he released or is he at Oak's place?

Answer (score 3):

In [Charizard's Burning Ambitions](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP134) (EP134), It is proved that Ash's Charizard is smaller and weaker than many wild Charizards which lived in  Charicific Valley. In the end of the episode he leaves him there not permanently released but for training. But he does come for his aid in his fights, when Ash needed him and returns back to Charicific Valley after matches. He (Charizard) even starts a romantic relationship with Charla (female Charizard owned by Liza at Charicific Valley).

Sometime after Diamond and Pearl series and before [The Fires of a Red-Hot Reunion!](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/BW116), Charizard left Charicific Valley and went to live with Professor Oak.

Refer [this link](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Charizard) of bulbapedia for his detailed journey.

<sub>**Note: I have seen most of these episodes, so I can verify that bulbapedia is right here.**</sub>